# How to make sure a pointer to a memory address is valid?

Tags: c++

I wrote the following function:

```
template <typename T> void SetPointer(DWORD64 base, vector<DWORD>Offsets, T value){
base = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD64*>(base);
for (int i = 0; i < Offsets.size() - 1; i++){
    base = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD64*>(base + Offsets[i]);
}
*reinterpret_cast<T*>(base + Offsets[Offsets.size() - 1]) = value;
}
```

It works perfectly, except that I'd like to have checks to make sure the address is valid and that it won't cause a crash, but I haven't found any way that works well to do that. What would be the best way to acheive this?

Edit:
This did the trick for what I need:

```
template <typename T> void SetPointer(DWORD64 base, vector<DWORD>Offsets, T value){
if (base == 0) return;
base = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD64*>(base);
for (int i = 0; i < Offsets.size() - 1; i++){
    base = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD64*>(base + Offsets[i]);
    if (base == Offsets[i] || base == 0) return;
}
*reinterpret_cast<T*>(base + Offsets[Offsets.size() - 1]) = value;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: You can't, there is no way to know (aside nullptr/0)

Comment: But if you're curious  you can play with signals, especially handling `SIGSEGV`. But that's bad practice as standard doesn't say anything about dereferencing invalid pointer, thus it's **undefined behaviour**. But it *just Works*™.

Comment: *I'd like to have checks to make sure the address is valid* -- Why?  Fix the bug in your code that provided the bad pointer.

Comment: Can't fix it, the issue is that the pointer is valid when the game is loaded and invalid when the game is on loading screen etc.

Comment: So don't point to something that can be invalidated.  This is no different than when a programmer points to a `std::vector's` internal buffer, and something mutates the vector, invalidating the pointer that was pointing to that location.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: It's impossible.

Long version:
Windows has functions called `IsBadXxxPtr` here is what a renowned Microsoft programmer has to say about them and their functionality:

[`IsBadXxxPtr` should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563)

Comment: IsBadXxxPtr should really be rewritten to look at the page tables instead of usingSEH.